# php changes variable but not in default value of a textbox

Tags: cakephp, post, cakephp-2.0

I dont understand the behaviour I am having.
I have this two pieces of codes on my view:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('Invoice',array('default' => $myValue));
```

and

```
echo "</br>this is my value". $myValue;
```

The first piece of code is the one I POST to the server and the second piece is just an echo. Whenever I post the form, I expect the $myValue to change, but in this case only the echo part changes correctly.

My question is: How come $myValue doesn't change in the default value of the textbox, while the $myValue does change when I just Echo it?

Note that both piece of codes are on the same page, so there is no difference in how the variables are provided.

Comment: consider posting a portion of your controller's code. It's hard to guess what's goin on just from the code from the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cakephp form helper's hidden function havent attribute default. 
If you want to assign value to that hidden input , you can pass that variable from controller to `$this->request->data['ModelName']['HiddenInputName'] = $myValue`
Or in view you can use this syntax

```
$this->Form->input(
     'inputname', 
     array(
          'value' => $myValue, 
          'type' => 'hidden'
     )
);
```

I think both of them can help you.